# Call a function from one polymer component to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer

I use Polymer, Html and Javascript.

I want to find any easy way to call a function from one polymer component to another. 
Let me describe what I want to achieve.

I have polymer component `myComponent`. In this component container with button called `start`:

```
<button on-click="_start" id="start">XyZ</button>
```

and also second component (let's say it is child component, because it is in `myComponent`, where I have got function `_addNew` in `<script>` section.

Now I want to fire `_addNew` function by clicking button with `#start` id. 
My question is how can I call a function from one polymer component when this function is placed in another?

I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understood correctly, basically what you want to do is fire from one component and listen in the other one.

So you fire from myComponent, in the _start method like:

```
this.fire('add:new');
```

and then to listen to the add:new event in your other component by adding a listener, for this specific event name:

```
listeners: {
   'add:new': '_addNew'
},
```

if it's not explicit enough, please do read the [Polymer documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html) it's a very nice and well explained documentation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is not working, because this.fire is going "up", to the parent component, not to a child component.

In my case this one help:

`this.$$('component-name').function-name();`

Comment: Of course javascript events are bubbling up, but I'm not sure using this.$$() is your best shot. It will only be good for returning the first element, which is true and working for now but not necessarily in the future.

Comment: it should be this.$$('#<id>') :P just saying